# Why does for-of not skip empty slots of a sparse Array? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, iteration, sparse-matrix, for-of-loop

As the title says, why does `for-of` run the loop body with the *loop variable* bound to `undefined` for indices not in the `Array`, while other iteration constructs (`forEach()`, `for-in`, etc.) don't?

## *Clarification*: As many misunderstood the question

It is ***not*** about:

- <del>iterating over `TypedArray`s</del> (which cannot be sparse) or <del>***any*** other class</del>
- <del>how to "correctly" iterate</del> over a sparse `Array` (every other method seems to work in the expected way)
- <del>skipping `undefined` elements</del> in an `Array`

---

Is the following *informal* description [found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) incorrect?

> The `for...of` statement [...] invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

I.e. it is also invoked for non-existent properties.

```js
const sparse = [0, 1, 2] // Was [0, , 2], but some are unfamiliar with this syntax 
                         // or think it creates the array [0, undefined, 2]
delete sparse[1]
for (let e of sparse) console.log('for-of', e)
// Contrast with:
sparse.forEach(e => console.log('forEach', e))
for (let i in sparse) console.log('for-in', sparse[i])
console.log('map', sparse.map(e => e)) // Note, prints incorrectly in the snippet
                                       // console, check browser console
// etc.
```

Is this the intended behaviour ([**Yes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885894/579078)) & why was it designed in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for..of` calls the Array iterator method, which is described [in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayiterator).

> (2) Let iterator be ObjectCreate(%ArrayIteratorPrototype%, «‍[[IteratedObject]], [[ArrayIteratorNextIndex]], [[ArrayIterationKind]]»).
>
> (4) Set iterator’s [[ArrayIteratorNextIndex]] internal slot to 0.

Then, when the iterator is iterated over, in [22.1.5.2.1 %ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next:](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%arrayiteratorprototype%.next):

> (6) Let index be the value of the [[ArrayIteratorNextIndex]] internal slot of O.
>
> (10) If index ≥ len, then
>
> (10) (a) Set the value of the [[IteratedObject]] internal slot of O to undefined.
>
> (10) (b) Return CreateIterResultObject(undefined, true).
>
> (11) **Set the value of the [[ArrayIteratorNextIndex]] internal slot of O to index+1**.
>
> (create iterator result object whose value is `array[index]`)

In other words - the iterator iterates starting at index 0, and increments the index by 1 every time `.next()` is called. It does not check to see if the array actually *has* an item at that index (which a sparse array will not) - it just checks that the index is less than the `.length` of the array.

With `for..in`, on the other hand, all *enumerable* properties are iterated over, and an array's own enumerable properties *do not include* sparse array indicies.

```js
const sparse = [0, , 2];
console.log(sparse.hasOwnProperty('0'));
console.log(sparse.hasOwnProperty('1'));
```

So yes, this is intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Re: *> It does not check to see if the array actually has an item at that index*, I had a hard time interpreting the spec, there is `14. Let elementValue be Get(a, elementKey)` and `15. ReturnIfAbrupt(elementValue)`. `Get` calls `.[[Get]]`, which has `2. Let desc be O.[[GetOwnProperty]](P)` and `3. ReturnIfAbrupt(desc)`.. so for an index that is not in the Array, wouldn't this result in an abrupt completion (`continue`? or `throw`?)

Comment: The [Get](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-o-p) algorithm does not throw, and returns `array.[[Get]](elementKey, array)`, which does not find the key anywhere, and eventually gets to `c. If parent is null, return undefined.`. Accessing a property which does not exist in an object simply returns `undefined` - it does not throw (trying to access a property of `undefined` or `null`, on the other hand, will throw) - so there's no abrupt completion here.

Comment: No sorry, it does